# Custom EnumConverter being ignored by WebAPI databinding

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following `enum` and `EnumConverter`:

```cs
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEventType {
  Unknown,
  URLEvent
}

public class MyEnumConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public MyEnumConverter(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            var enumString = (string)value;
            return EnumExtensions.GetValueFromDescription(enumString, EnumType);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

I also have a WebAPI controller that accepts an object that contains a property of the above enum type:

```cs
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
   [Route("events")]
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult HandlePost([FromBody] MyEvent myEvent)
   {
       // Do whatever here
   }
}

public class MyEvent 
{
   public MyEventType eventType {get; set;}
}
```

However, if I `POST` `{"eventType" : "URLEvent"}` to the controller, I get an error: "The JSON value could not be converted ..." Placing a break-point in `ConvertFrom()` I can see that the it is never being called.

**What do I need to do to get the Web API databinding to use my EnumConverter?**

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using, are you using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft (Json.Net)?

Comment: Why don't you use `services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>{var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternatives to solve your current problem：

First：`System.Text.Json serialization`:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    // Or .AddControllers(...)
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
        opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
    })
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

Second：`Newtonsoft.Json`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

And then:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Test Result:

[image]

[image]